# plpythonu function to execute python script on localhost does not work

Tags: python, postgresql, greenplum

I am trying to create a function as shown below:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_run(usename text) 
    RETURNS void
    AS $$
    import subprocess
    from subprocess import call
    subprocess.call('/test/tty/sessions.py' + usename , shell=True)
   $$
   LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```

and the function suppose to execute the /test/tty/sessions.py script which is locally available on the server plus it has to take 1 argument in this case **usename**. I have tried so many different options but does not seem to work. Any ideas/suggestions please.. thanks..

Comment: is it giving any error while executing function?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run the script `test/tty/sessions.py<username>` where `<username>` is the contents of the username variable. Change the `+` to a `,`

Comment: thanks for your comment... highly appreciated but I found out the issue was to do with  subprocess.call('/test/tty/sessions.py' + usename , shell=True) and the fact that you have to leave a blank space between the name of the script and the argument as it concatenated all together. So only by making like :subprocess.call('/test/tty/sessions.py ' + usename , shell=True) then it worked..  Goodness is working now.. Thanks again.